# Ставится ли запятая после «без меня»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Без меня(?) твоя жизнь была бы действительно скучной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Без меня твоя жизнь была бы действительно скучной.**
Не нужны в этом предложении никакие запятые. Предложение простое, двусоставное, распространенное, неосложненное (в нем нет однородных членов, обращений, причастных или деепричастных оборотов, вводных слов или обособленных членов).

Без меня она никогда не меняет ни одного слова в моих документах и рукописях. [Геннадий Горелик. Андрей Сахаров. Наука и свобода (2004)]

Без меня никто же не найдет убийцу! [Ольга Новикова. Каждый убивал // «Сибирские огни», 2012]

Конечно же, можно подобрать контекст, в котором "без меня" выделяется знаками.

Со мной твоя жизнь будет яркой, радостной, без меня — скучной.
Твоя жизнь будет скучной. Без меня.